# Mal visionado de animaciones movimiento Xamarin Forms

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, animación

Estoy teniendo algunos problemas con el desarrollo multiplataforma de Xamarin, teniendo una pantalla donde necesito desplazar automáticamente elementos con una animación de forma más rápida o más lenta.

En android e iOs las animaciones se ven de forma correcta, no se si porque el movimiento es diferente o porque la resolución de pantalla al ser menor que en un sobremesa no se aprecia ese problema. El problema viene cuando lanzo la aplicación para UWP donde cuando observas el movimiento de los elementos te da la sensación de ir a tirones o vibrando, si el movimiento es hacia arriba o hacia abajo se aprecia menos, pero si el movimiento es lateral se aprecia de forma clara incluso llegando a molestar mucho.

No se si alguien ha podido encontrarse con este problema, para las animaciones utilizo el metodo .translateto() del siguiente modo:

```
ElementoEstimulo[indice].boton.TranslateTo(desplazamientoX, desplazamientoY, (uint)tiempo);
```

De este modo hago que el elemento (una imagen o botón) recorra la pantalla en un numero de segundos, de entre 10 y 4, con 10 segundos como el movimiento es lento no se ve tan mal, pero cuando intento que el movimiento sea rápido, es tan molesto que llega incluso a marear de las vibraciones o saltos de las imágenes, no se si alguien podría echarme una mano con ello.

Muchas gracias de antemano, perdonad las molestias.
un saludo, Marcos.

Comment: he probado a buscar otros elementos que mover pero no importa, todos se mueven igual